# Strange artefacts on objects behind glass in Unity 5

Tags: unity, materials, bug

I think the image speaks for itself. Basically all those little dots shouldn't be there, and they go away as soon as I hide or move the glass. Any ideas on how to fix it?

[image]

This is the glass materials settings:

[image]

Comment: Seems like your "glass" has a material that stops light in X shapes. Can you post the material itself alongside the glass object's details?

Comment: Sure, what do you mean by glass objects details? Is it the import settings?

Comment: Have you disabled shadowcasting on your glass object? It looks like the engine is trying to apply a dithered shadow for a translucent shadowing effect, but it doesn't quite work for this case.

Comment: No but when I turn it off the artefacts go away.

Comment: That material shouldn't really have any shadows. Just disable shadow casting for glasses.

Comment: How can I do that for a certain material? I was looking at the actual models settings.